# Extract sub path from url with regex

Tags: python, regex, url

I have this url:

```
 http://www.example.com/en/news/2016/07/17/1207151/%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%87%D8%A8%D8%B1-
```

I am going to extract `1207151` here.

here is my regext:

```
pattern = '(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)+[^/]+[^/]+[^/]+[^/]/(?<field1>[^/]+)/'
```

but it's wrong!

what is my mistake?

Comment: Is the section you want always the last before the fine `/`?

Comment: @Syntac i want to get the digits before the `17/` and after the `/%D9...`

exactly the `1207151`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex in python code:

```
>>> url = 'http://www.example.com/en/news/2016/07/17/1207151/%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D8%B1%D9%87%D8%A8%D8%B1-'
>>> re.search(r'^https?://(?:([^/]+)/){7}', url).group(1)
'1207151'
```

`([^/]+)/){7}` will match 1 or more of any non-forward-slash and a `/` 7 times, giving us last match in captured group #1.

Comment: Hello, may I ask why you used a non capturing group in your regex pattern? I would like to know what would happen if you omit it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you make it capturing group, regex will still work same. However we should avoid capturing when not required to save memory. However in this example you will need to use `.group(2)` to get last component.

Comment: I understand. I checked and if I am not mistaken in case of capturing we need to extract another group in this case `0`. So the only difference is we have more groups.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple things going on.

First you'll need to properly escape all of your `/`s. You've got most of them, but missed a couple:

```
(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)+[^\/]+[^\/]+[^\/]+[^\/]\/(?<field1>[^\/]+)\/
```

From here, you have a number of "1 or more not /" in a row that can be reduced:

```
[^\/]+[^\/]+[^\/]+ ==> [^\/]{3,}
```

But that's not what you meant to do, you meant to have many blocks of "non /" followed by a "/" and based on your example, you want it 6 times before using your named capture group.

```
([^\/]+\/){6}
```

Here's what works:

```
http[s]?:\/\/([^\/]+\/){6}(?<field1>[^\/]+)\/
```

And you can see it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/kkqwRJ/2

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print re.search(r'.*/([^/]+)/.*',s).group(1)
```

Comment: Can you describe the assumptions that you have made about the input string?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.